# как выполнить скрипт при запуске docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sh

Скрипт генерит сертификаты, хотелось бы вызвать его при первом запуске docker-compose, есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose.yml:

```
varsion: '3'

    services:
          build: ./script
```

В одной папке должен лежать docker-compose.yml и папка script в которой лежит Dockerfile в котором можно описать запуск вашего скрипта

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет опция **command:**

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]